# Managing Signal Handling for daemons that fork()

Tags: perl, daemon, signal-handling

I want to write a robust daemon in perl that will run on Linux and am following the template described [in this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766397/how-can-i-run-a-perl-script-as-a-system-daemon-in-linux). However there are a few differences in my situation: First I am using [Parallel::ForkManager](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Parallel::ForkManager) `start() and next`; to fork on an event immediately followed by `exec('handle_event.pl')`

In such a situation, I have the following questions:

1. Where should I define my signal handlers. Should I define them in the parent (the daemon) and assume that they will be inherited in the children?
2. If I run `exec('handle_event.pl')` will the handlers get inherited across the exec (I know that they are inherited across the `fork`)?
3. If I re-define a new signal handler in `handle_event.pl` will this definition override the one defined in the parent?
4. What are best practices in a situation like this?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `exec` replaces the whole process code with the code that will be executed. As signal handlers are code in the process image, they cannot be inherited across an `exec`, so `exec` will reset the signal handling dispositions of handled signals to their default states (ignored signals will remain ignored). You will therefore need to install any signal handling in the `exec`ed process when it starts up.

Comment: Not all signals will be set to default, if a signal is ignored it will still be ignored after the exec.

Answer (score 6):

When you fork, the child process has the same signal handlers as the parent.  When you exec, any ignored signals remain ignored; any handled signals are reset back to the default handler.

Comment: Thanks - This is one of those times when I wish accepting more than one answer was possible :)