# daemonize perl process

Tags: perl, syslog

I am trying to daemonize a perl process example test to syslog.

1) in the perl script it already log into rotate log file but I would like to log the daemonize for case of when things goes wrong before log get create
2) currently I am doing 
    sudo /usr/sbin/daemonize -u User -a -e /home/users/me/log/log.log /home/users/me/test

It already working but the issue is that the log file will get big and the only way to handle the log file is if daemonize is stop.

So I am trying to log into syslog so I am doing

sudo /usr/sbin/daemonize -u User -a -e /dev/stderr /home/users/me/test | logger

this will have permission error when write to stderr.  If I don't run as User it get log fine but for security reason I have to run my daemonize as User.

I am stuck any help is appreciate

my test
sub main{
    my $i = 0;
    for($i=0; $i < 10 ; $i++){
        print "this is a test " . $i . " \n";
    }
}

main(@ARG);

Note I also tried the 2>&1 but does not work

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/766397/how-can-i-run-a-perl-script-as-a-system-daemon-in-linux - and here you go..

Comment: The other problem I suspect you have here (although I'm not sure exactly what /usr/sbin/daemonize does) is that you're piping the output to logger outside of the daemonize.  I suspect it may close standard output (a standard thing to do when daemonizing), at which point you've lost the pipe to logger and logger will just exit.

Comment: give a try to [immortal](https://immortal.run) `immortal -l your-command`

Answer (score 2):

You might do better to use Daemon::Daemonize from CPAN or something like it.  It allows you to automatically redirect STDOUT and STDERR.  It claims to handle all the setpgrp stuff you need.

I think if you combine this with using Sys::Syslog (also from CPAN) you can do all of what you need to do without out relying on /usr/sbin/daemonize and with a little more control over what is actually happening with your program.

You seem to have two distinct problems:

1) Daemonizing your program.
2) Logging to syslog.

Both are problems which are better solved directly in your Perl code.  As well as Daemon::Daemonize there is Proc::Daemonize.  I don't have an opinion on their relative merits, I've just used Daemon::Daemonize in the past.  Either one would get your program running as a daemon.

For writing to syslog, using Sys::Sylog will do the heavy lifting for you.  It's not a simple redirect, but it will allow you to send log messages and not worry about log rotation.