# Can I execute a multiline command in Perl's backticks?

Tags: perl, solaris, unix, nohup

In Unix, I have a process that I want to run using nohup. However this process will at some point wait at a prompt where I have to enter `yes` or `no` for it to continue. So far, in Unix I have been doing the following

```
nohup myprocess <<EOF
y
EOF
```

So I start the process 'myprocess' using nohup and pipe in a file with 'y' then close the file. The lines above are effectively three seperate commands - i.e. I hit enter on the first line in UNIX, then I get a prompt where I enter 'y' and then press enter to then finally type 'EOF' and hit return again.

I want to know execute this in Perl but I am not sure how I can execute this command as it is over three lines. I don't know if the following will work....

```
my $startprocess = `nohup myprocess <<EOF &
y
EOF
`
```

Please help - thank you!

Comment: Perhaps the Unix & Linux stackexchange could help: http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: When you don't know if something will work, write a small test program and find out. :)

Answer (score 5):

I think your proposal will work as is. If not, try replacing the redirect with a pipe:

```
my $startprocess = `(echo "y" | nohup myprocess) &`;
```

Also, depending on WHY you are doing a `nohup`, please look at the following pure Perl daemonizing approach using `Proc::Daemon` : [How can I run a Perl script as a system daemon in linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766397/how-can-i-run-a-perl-script-as-a-system-daemon-in-linux)

Answer (score 2):

[Expect](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Expect.pm) for interactive programs can be used as well.