# Use linux script to make a continuous rake task running (start, stop etc)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, rake

I have a rake task which parses a streaming API and enters data into database. The streaming API is live feed and the rake task should run continuously for the live data to enter the database. The rake task once called will run continuously and parse the data. Now i have started the rake task and it is running. The problem is that if i close the terminal or reboot the server, the rake task wil be stopped. So, i want a script in linux (something like the one used to start, or stop apache server), which does the following:

```
1. start the rake task by calling rake command (rake parse:stream) from the RAILS-ROOT (application directory of Rails app)
2. stop the rake task by killing the process.
3. start the rake task automatically when the server reboots.
```

i am not familiar to linux scripts and i dont know where to start. i am using ubuntu server. can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an article that might help you also. It discussed various options for managing Ruby applications and their related processes:
http://michaelvanrooijen.com/articles/2011/06/08-managing-and-monitoring-your-ruby-application-with-foreman-and-upstart/

Answer (score 1):

You need to run your script as a daemon. When I create this kind of startup scripts I usually make 2 files, one that stays in `/etc/init.d` and handles the `start/stop/status/restart` commands and another one that actually does the job and gets called by the first script.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766397/how-can-i-run-a-perl-script-as-a-system-daemon-in-linux) is one solution, and although the daemon script is written in perl, you want to run some command lines only, so daemonizing a perl script could do your job easily.

If you want, there are also [ruby gems](http://daemons.rubyforge.org/) for daemonizing scripts, so you can write a script in ruby that does the rake tasks.

And if you want to go hardcore, there are solutions for writing bash scripts that can daemonize, but I'm not sure I would recommend a solution like that; at least I find them pretty difficult to use.

Comment: so should I install perl for using the first solution

Answer (score 1):

[Take a look](https://gist.github.com/1155351) at how Github's [Resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque) project does it.

Essentially they create tasks for starting/restarting/stopping a particular task, in this case `resque:work`. Note that the `restart_workers` task simply invokes the other tasks, stop and start. It should be really easy to change this for what you want.