# Creating a pid_file while using Proc::Daemon::Init

Tags: perl, daemon

I've been following the explanation in [run a perl script as a daemon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766397/how-can-i-run-a-perl-script-as-a-system-daemon-in-linux).  I would like to create the `pid_file` within the perl script.  After going through the documentation I was sure that the following piece of code would do it:

```
use Proc::Daemon;
Proc::Daemon::Init({ pid_file => "/var/run/theprocess.pid"} );
```

To make a long story short.  Id didn't work. I've also tried with the `Proc::Daemon->new()` operator and it didn't work either.  What could I be missing?

Comment: Please provide more details on "didn't work" in both cases. Didn't compile? Runtime error? Error message (and if so what is it)? hanging? etc...

Comment: Didn't create the pid file.  Worked perfectly as the daemon detached and it did run.

Comment: Was there any error on STDERR?

Comment: No errors on STDERR that I could find.  Nothing on the console or /var/log/syslog.

Comment: Change pid_file location to `/tmp`? What happens?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing any details it's hard to tell, but most likely it's one of 2 things:

- Either `pid_file` doesn't support a full path. This is unlikely but possible considering that [POD](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Proc%3a%3aDaemon) example involves separate `work_dir` argument and path-less `pid_file` value:

  ```
  my $daemon = Proc::Daemon->new(
       work_dir     => '/working/daemon/directory',
       pid_file     => 'pid.txt',
       exec_command => 'perl /home/my_script.pl',
  );
  ```

  Based on the current code in the module that's not the case (e.g. the example merely doesn't show a valid usage with full path, but such usage is fine); but it could be a new functionality missing from your older module version. Again, unlikely.
- Or, the file you're writing to can't be created, either because the directory is missing or due to permissioning issue. If that's the case there should be something on STDERR looking like "*Can not open pid_file xxxx*" . Just as FYI, the file is opened for read-write mode (`+>`).

Answer (score 1):

Actually the problem was that the debian package that installs Proc::Daemon::Init is for version 0.3 which doesn't have the functionality to create the pid files.  I ended up doing something like:

```
use Proc::Daemon;
use Proc::PID::File;

Proc::Daemon::Init();
if (Proc::PID::File->running()) {
    exit;
}
```