# Nginx not executing .pl extensions. It downloads the file instead

Tags: perl, nginx

I am using an Nginx server.

If I access `index.pl` it downloads the file instead of executing it.

I'm pretty sure this is to do with `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

Here is a copy

```
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;

server_name domain.com;

root /var/www/domain.com;
index index.html index.php index.pl;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

    # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
}
```

As you can see, I have already added `index.pl` to the end of the `index` list.

What else do I need to get it working?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11667489/how-to-run-cgi-scripts-on-nginx, https://www.scalescale.com/tips/nginx/serve-perl-scripts-nginx/#

Comment: @mob Hello, thank you for these links, they helped me solve my issue!

Comment: @ChrisBoyd: If you have a solution then please post it as an answer. Any question you post should be much more useful to others searching for a solution to a similar issue, and at present this page is pretty much empty.