# Run script as daemon with proc::Daemon module

Tags: perl, daemon, redhat

I've got a perl script I'm writing for a school assignment that needs to be run as a daemon and do certain actions when it recives signals. I read this thread [How can I run a Perl script as a system daemon in linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766397/how-can-i-run-a-perl-script-as-a-system-daemon-in-linux/766412#766412) and tried doing what the top reply suggested but if I run my program I don't see a PID for it.

Here's the basics of my current code.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Proc::Daemon;

Proc::Daemon::Init;

my $fname = "/tmp/filename.txt";
my $datafile;
my @students;

sub filefind {finds a filename }    

sub readData {reads text in file }

sub createhash { makes hash out of data }

sub printa {prints sorted data }

sub alpha { sorts data }

sub revalpha { sorts data }

filefind();

readData();

$SIG{ USR1 } = \&alph;

$SIG{ USR2 } = \&revalph;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you don't have a loop for your code. Your program just **exit** after running `filefind()` and `readData()`. You can comments `Proc::Daemon::Init;` to see the procedure

To solve the problem, you can add a loop at the end:

```
while (1) {
    sleep 10;
}
```